# Find file with hours|minutes|seconds in its name

Tags: ksh

I am writing a script that looks for files with a specific name to move them to an FTP location. Most files show up with this naming convention

```
PRODUCTNAME_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt
```

Some however show up with a BAD (for damaged good) suffix in the name

```
PRODUCTNAME_YYYYMMDD_BAD.txt
```

I want to skip the latter. Only process the former. This is my code

```
rundate=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
filename=PRODUCTNAME_${rundate}*.txt
test -s $ddw_data/${filename}
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
      ...Throw error...
else
      ...Move the file to FTP location...
fi
```

This will process both files. This is wrong.

Since 'HHMMSS' in the filename will not match the system time, I am not sure how to proceed.

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: `find -name somepattern -exec ...`

Comment: Do you need to parse the time in the file names? Or do you just want to exclude all files that match `*_BAD.txt`?

Comment: Only exclude all files that match *_BAD.txt.

Comment: So, something like `for f in *; do if [ "$f" != "${f$$_BAD.txt}" ]; then throw_error; else move_file; fi`? That command assumes that all files in your directory match `PRODUCTNAME_...`

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I think this will do the trick.

Comment: Oh, I made a typo. It should be `"${f%%_BAD.txt}"`. And the `for` loop needs to end with `done`.

Comment: I was trying my hand with sed and found this work as well. I created a list of all the `PRODUCTNAME_` files on my system and ran this command `sed -i '/_BAD.txt/d' file_list`. It removes from the list all the file names with BAD in their name. Different approach but it works.